# Cannot add new contributions anymore - DB Error: no such field

Tags: civicontribute, database

We are running CiviCRM 5.42.1 on Wordpress. We had no issues with adding contributions up until a week ago. We've not updated Civi recently - last update was more than 5 or 6 months ago.
I get an error when adding a contribution for any contact on the system.
I select contribution -> New Contribution. Fill in the form, click on Save and get this error (first part of the error shown before the full exception trace). As such, we cannot record donations to our org anymore. Urgently need some help/suggestions on to resolve.

Type    DB_Error
Code    -19
Message DB Error: no such field
Mode    16
UserInfo    INSERT INTO `civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages` (`contact_id` , `data` , `entity_table` , `entity_id` , `invoke_contact_id` ) VALUES ( 6287 , '{"entity":"Activity","id":20448,"body":"%display_name has created activity."}' , 'Activity' , 20448 , 203 ) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'message' in 'NEW']
DebugInfo   INSERT INTO `civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages` (`contact_id` , `data` , `entity_table` , `entity_id` , `invoke_contact_id` ) VALUES ( 6287 , '{"entity":"Activity","id":20448,"body":"%display_name has created activity."}' , 'Activity' , 20448 , 203 ) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'message' in 'NEW']
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field in /home/iskcon/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Civimobile just had a release where the message column was removed. I suspect the extension on your site was updated. Are you using advanced logging (administer - system settings - misc - logging)? If so, then the logging tables/triggers might be out of date. You can fix by running `cv flush -T` or if you can get into the UI then `civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1`

Comment: Thank for your suggestions Demerit. Yes, we are using logging. I ran civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1, but that did not fix it. I then disabled logging and now it works. I'm able to add a contribution successfully. Really appreciate your help on this one! I don't think we need logging enabled anyway for our org, but hopefully after we upgrade Civi and our extensions, and need to enable logging again, logging works.